# How do i match this string?

Tags: javascript, regex

The string I have to parse is

```
[]123 []456
```

After `[]`,  there can be any kind of characters, not only numbers.

I am trying to get the following matches:

```
[]123
[]456
```

I tried

```
/\[](?!\[])+/g
```

but only get `[]` and `[]`.

Comment: Use `/\[]\d+/g`

Comment: Thinks, but it's not only numbers, it's none '[]' string @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: You are only matching `[]` and after that repeating a negative lookahead which is non consuming. Matching any char except the square brackest `\[][^\][]+`

Comment: If you aim to match digits and letters, this one is enough:
    \[]\w+

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\[](?!\[])+` pattern matches `[]` with `\[]` and then asserts the position is not followed with `[]` substring. There is no `[]` after both `[]`, so they are returned as matches. Note there is no point in quantifying the lookahead, it is only checking if its pattern matches or not and returns true or false, so it is in fact just checked once.

You can use

```js
const s = "[]123[]456";
console.log( s.split(/(?!^)(?=\[])/) );
console.log( s.match(/\[][^]*?(?=\[]|$)/g) );
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/SAdbyD/1) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/SAdbyD/2).

*Split solution*

The `(?!^)(?=\[])` pattern matches any location between a non-start position (`(?!^)` means any position but start of string) and a `[]` substring (`(?=\[])` is a positive lookahead that matches a location immediately followed with `[]`).

*Match solution*

The `/\[][^]*?(?=\[]|$)/g` regex matches all occurrences of

- `\[]` - `[]` substring
- `[^]*?` - any 0 or more chars, as few as possible, up to
- `(?=\[]|$)` - either `[]` or end of string.